# Architechture of service application in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I need some help with the architechture of a WCF application. The will be a number of services that should be available to serve a number of different clients, e.g.

- ASP.Net application (JavaScript and/or Silverlight)
- iPhone
- Windows Mobile
- Android

Some of the services need authentication and some will be available w/o authentication.

I need some advice on the services that need authentication, I want to use username/password credentials over SSL.

How (if possible/recommended for all the client types) should I design this in WCF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and should) decouple Authentication from service implementation so that you can vary these independently. This is possible by implementing (or reusing) a [ServiceAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.aspx).

The nice thing about these is that they can be defined in .config and you can code your entire service without knowing anything about how the user authenticated.

If you need to know more about the user, you can use [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx).

---

To implement username/password validation, implement a [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that answer large parts of my problem. Regarding the username/password authentication itself, do you have any recommendations on the implementation?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer that question as well :)

Comment: @FredrikJansson: I am in a same situation like you now, i have wcf services which will be consumed by many clients like web application, ipad and mobile etc. Can i know what architechture you followed for authentication ? did you use ServiceAuthorizationManager along with username and password validation ? if so, can you tell me how you achieved that ?